# How to check how many calls has been made with my LUIS application?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I googled but i didn't find anything where can i see how many calls has been made with my application.

They have 10k free calls, after that, must pay for their services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the LUIS portal you can click `Download logs` from the publishing window.

Otherwise you can get them via the LUIS Programmatic API:

https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/5739a8c71984550500affdf9